# install4j: boolean as command line options

Tags: install4j

In my installer I have a couple of optional downloadable components which are deselected by default. Is there any way to mark them as selected when using starting the installer in quiet mode without using a response/varfile?

For example I have the following lines in the varfile:

`sys.component.component1$Boolean=false
sys.component.component2$Boolean=true
sys.component.component3$Boolean=false`

These tell the installer to only install the second optional component.

Is there any way to automatically map these to a variable name, or have them in any way settable without a varfile, straight from the command line?

Something along the lines of `./setup.sh -q -dir /path/to/install -Vcomp1notselect -Vcomp3notselect`

In the installer I do a `context.getInstallationComponentById("component1").isSelected()` check to see if I need to perform some custom actions with that component.

Answer (score 1):

```
-Vsys.component.component1$Boolean=false
```

would work on the command line. Alternatively, you can use

-Vcomp1deselect=true

and add a "Run script" action with script like:

```
if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase((String)context.getVariable("comp1deselect"))) {
    context.getInstallationComponentById("component1").setSelected(false);
}
```